# CSS sliding underline import into wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, codepen

I have a question related to the css sliding underline functionality as described on codepen.io. How can I integrate it into a locally hosted wordpress website? I tried the HTML import 2.0 plugin , but didn't go  quite well. Parts of css i can add as extra CSS in theme customizer section, but the underline effect based on the `<hr>` tag can't be applied, since the html code isn't there for the pre-existing theme menu. How to proceed?

Comment: I mean: the hr-tag

Comment: [Create a child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) and modify the main menu according to your needs.

Comment: Dear Hector (?), Thanks for your answer. If I understand the linked document correctly, I can (partially) override the original CSS style sheet and add extra functions to the functions.php file. So after an update of the theme I won't loose the additional settings I included. Great! But how about the html aspect? How to replace or slightly change the pre-existing menu structure with an external menu structure written in html? I see separate pages for example  a sidebar or footer, or any other page that relates to a single menu item. But I can't find the code inside that makes up the menu list.

Comment: With child themes you can basically replace most stuff from the original theme (CSS, templates, et cetera) with your own. In your case, chances are you need to edit something either in header.php or in functions.php, so I would copy both into the child theme and make all changes there. (And yes, the name's Héctor :))

Comment: Thanks Hector, for your clear explanation. So in header.php I should probably find some reference to a function in function.php which constructs the primary menu structure? So there is not something very similar to an unsorted list structure as in given codepen: https://codepen.io/Uma/pen/OPWxmm ?

Comment: Hard to say without looking at some code, Lucas. That's something you need to figure out on your own, or hire someone else to do the job if you really don't have the time to learn the skills needed for this (eg. because you're on a deadline or something).